# Can someone patent something I invented if sell it but I don't patent it

Tags: patentability, public

From my understanding if I manufacture and sell a product publicly before applying for a patent then it can not be patented. If that is the case then does that also prevent anyone else from apply for a patent on the same product which would then prevent me from manufacturing and selling the product.  If that is also the case it would not stop them from manufacturing and selling it legally though right?

Comment: This is also answered here: [What can I do to someone who stole my idea and patented it?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/16700/what-can-i-do-to-someone-who-stole-my-idea-and-patented-it)

Comment: Is there still anything unclear that isn't answered by the duplicate question? If yes please narrow the question down.